# How do I open bootstrap modal in this code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please help with my twitter bootstrap modal. I cannot seem to open it. Modal suupposedly opens by clicking "login" but I really cant seem to implement it properly. Here's the code:

```
<nav class ="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class ="container-fluid">
        <div class ="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav nav-pills pull-left">
            <li><a href ="#"> Create a Project </a></li>
            <li><a href ="#"> Fund a Project </a></li>
            <li><a href ="#"> Collaborate </a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class ="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li><a href ="#"> About us </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign up </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a></li>
        </ul>

    <!--login modal-->
        <div  class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"> Login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p> Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `modal` works but it needs to be placed outside of the `navbar`, otherwise you will only be able to see it, not access it.

Also, make sure your JS files are in the proper order:

1. jQuery (first),
2. followed by BootstrapJS

Your navbar is also missing some HTML (for mobile, etc) which I added, this won't alter the modal so you can leave the nav the way you have it if you prefer and just follow everything else to make the modal work.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"> Create a Project </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Fund a Project </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Collaborate </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"> About us </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign up </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--login modal-->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Login</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <p>
    <div class="alert alert-info">Modal</div>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des
    morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960
    grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition
    et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas
    fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et,
    plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem I</p>
  <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de
    texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la
    vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et
    la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait
    que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus
    récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem I</p>
</div>
```